# Import CSV into MongoDB using a command (not mongoimport)

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to import CSV in MongoDB by issuing a command (e.g.: something from within the `mongo` shell) ?

I'm already aware of `mongoimport` but its a stand alone tool that runs on the OS.

Comment: What's wrong with mongoimport? The shell isn't made for this - if you don't want to use mongoimport you should use a driver in a programming language of your choice.

Comment: @wdberkeley nothing wrong, was just curious. I wanted to write a js script that I could run in mongo. And I wanted the script to do all the work, including import.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by using http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/ and some csv to json conversions like http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript

Comment: From the documentation it says: `filename` - Specifies the path of a JavaScript file to execute.
This will probably load the entire JSON file into memory, I want to be able to import large files.

Comment: `load` loads and runs a Javascript file - not really what is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you csv is formatted correctly if you get an error.

`mongoimport -d mydb -c myCollection --type csv --headerline --file < /path/to/yourfile.csv`

Comment: As I've mentioned in the title and in the question itself, "I'm already aware of mongoimport" and I was looking for other methods other than `mongoimport`.

Comment: unsophisticated method would be to convert see csv to json then cp the json into a mongo insert function in your shell. So db.mycollection.insert([ ...json])